# Crystal Report condition for Second Page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I need a second page on crystal report that 
depends on the value of the parameter 
on the first page.

Here's the code on the section before the next page:

> if {@delinquency_title} = "Statement of Tax Delinquency" 
>   then 
>   No NextPage

@delinquency_title - title on the first page

Statement of Tax Delinquency - value of the title

currently, it had an error

The second page must not exist if the value of the title is
Statement of Tax Delinquency

Comment: the error was the syntax in preventing the section created to display, based on a parameter, but I finally figure out the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I just click on the section expert and locate the section and add a code that will prevent from displaying the section

```
{@delinquency_title} = "Statement of Tax Delinquency"
```

I click supress in the x-2 button and the section was prevented to display based on the parameter's condition